# Why don't I have hot water after shutting off the water supply for a while?

Tags: hot-water

I have a 240 watt State Select 40 gallon water heater. I shut off the water supply for maybe 6 hours to replace faucet seats in the shower. I  turned off wrong breaker, and 2 days later no hot water at all.

What do I need to do to get my hot water heater working again?  Would I just need to replace the heating elements? Both elements?

I read also about dip tubes melting on other sites. Is this in my unit and  something I would need to replace?

I have replaced heating elements before so that's not new to me. The model number of my unit is EN6-40-DORS 110. Thank you.

Comment: Unless you also drained the heater there shouldn't be a problem. Does water flow from the hot tap? Has the correct breaker been on for at least a few hours?

Comment: And did you mean 240 *volt*?

Answer (score 1):

On the upper thermostat, there is a sensor that would trip if the water got too hot inside of the tank, BEFORE the TP valve would blow off (which we assume didn't happen because you didn't mention it). It's called an Energy Cut Off (ECO) switch. There is a red button on it. Open the upper access panel, you should see it there. Push the red button and if you hear it "click", it was tripped and it should work again after that. If not, or it doesn't click, it's something else. If it trips again really soon after resetting, an element was damaged.

And it's 240**V**, but it is **6,000** watts...